# Revit Pick element from WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, api, revit

I'm trying to pick an object in Revit when clicking a button without closing the Form.
the problem is when i click the button i can't interact with Revit.

here's the main code calling the Form and passing Revit as owner.

```
IWin32Window revit_window = new JtWindowHandle(ComponentManager.ApplicationWindow);
Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
IntPtr h = process.MainWindowHandle;

form.ShowDialog(revit_window);

public class JtWindowHandle : IWin32Window
{
    IntPtr _hwnd;

    public JtWindowHandle(IntPtr h)
    {
        Debug.Assert(IntPtr.Zero != h, "expected non-null window handle");

        _hwnd = h;
    }

    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get
        {
            return _hwnd;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the Form code to select the element:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        SelectionFilter1 selfilter1 = new SelectionFilter1();
        pickedRef1 = sel.PickObject(ObjectType.Element, selfilter1, "Select Family instance");
        Show();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Windows form is presumably not running as a modal form within a valid Revit API context.

Consequently, you are trying to access Revit and its API from outside. This is basically not possible. A workaround exists via the use of an [external event](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2018/05089477-4612-35b2-81a2-89c4f44370ea.htm).

This issue is currently also being discussed in the [Revit API discussion forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/bd-p/160) thread on [Revit API with WPF](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/revit-api-with-wpf/m-p/8209618).

The official approach is presented in the Revit SDK sample ModelessDialog/ModelessForm_ExternalEvent.

Many other discussions and soutions are listed by The Building Coder in the topic group on [Idling and External Events for Modeless Access and Driving Revit from Outside](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.28).