# WinForm with user selection; Which way to go?

Tags: c#, winforms, revit-api

I'm writing an Addin for Revit with the template of Jeremy Tammik, which creates me a Ribbon with Buttons.
I'm reading in an excel file, selecting lines and a starting point.

[My Ribbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KImCd.jpg)
[My WinForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCuNe.jpg)

After the User is finished with his input, he should click on a "Done" button (which is missing in my case^^) and it should generate some FamilyInstances in the Project without closing the WinForm.

#### My Problems:

- I can't use `ShowDialog()` right? Because this will create me a modal form and then i can't get any user input since the Revit Window is greyed out
- I can't use `Show()` right? Since my Code will just continue

#### My Question:

Can someone maybe help me to find the right approach for my problem. I'm not quite sure if my approach is even going to work at the end

#### What i've tried so far:

I tried to make a Transaction in the WinForm Class but i knew this wasn't going to work.
I'm thinking about a separate class which will save the user input and a second ExternalCommand Class which will execute the Transaction to create the FamilyInstances.
I looked into the SDK and found the ModelessForm_ExternalEvent but i was hard for me to understand it...
I also found these posts and tried to understand them:
https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/winform-focus-after-user-selection/td-p/7344224 
[Revit Pick element from WinForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51918495/revit-pick-element-from-winform)

#### My Code:

I have an App Class which creates the Ribbon and Buttons:

```
class App : IExternalApplication
{
    public Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication a)
    {
        // Ingenieurbau Reiter erstellen
        string engineerTabName = "Ingenieurbau Addin";
        a.CreateRibbonTab(engineerTabName);
        // Gruppen erstellen
        RibbonPanel lswPanel = a.CreateRibbonPanel(engineerTabName, "Lärmschutzwand");
        // Buttons hinzufügen
        AddLswPushButtons(lswPanel);
        AddTestPushButton(lswPanel);

        return Result.Succeeded;
    }

    private void AddLswPushButtons(RibbonPanel panel)
    {
        // Strings erzeugen
        string lswName1 = "LSW Daten einlesen";
        string lswAssemblyName1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        string lswClassName1 = "IngenieurbauAddin1.Lsw.DataInput";

        // ButtonData erzeugen
        PushButtonData lswPushButtonData1 = new PushButtonData(lswName1, lswName1, lswAssemblyName1, lswClassName1);

        // ButtonData dem Panel hinzufügen und in einen PushButton umwandeln
        PushButton lswPushButton1 = panel.AddItem(lswPushButtonData1) as PushButton;

        // ButtonBild einfügen
        lswPushButton1.LargeImage = PngImageSource("IngenieurbauAddin1.Resources.Excel.png");
    }
}
```

I have a DataInput Class which shows the Form:

```
[Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
class DataInput : IExternalCommand
{
    public Result Execute(
      ExternalCommandData commandData,
      ref string message,
      ElementSet elements)
    {
        UIApplication uiapp = commandData.Application;
        UIDocument uidoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument;
        Application app = uiapp.Application;
        Document doc = uidoc.Document;

        // Form instanziieren
        DataInputForm dataInputForm = new DataInputForm(uidoc);
        // Form starten
        dataInputForm.Show();

        return Result.Succeeded;
    }
}
```

And this is my DataInputForm Class (i know that the `PlaceFamily` doesn't work):

```
public partial class DataInputForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    private UIDocument UIDocument { get; set; }
    private Document Document { get; set; }

    public DataInputForm(UIDocument uiDocument)
    {
        UIDocument = uiDocument;
        Document = uiDocument.Document;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSelectPoint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        SelectionHelper selectionHelper = new SelectionHelper(Document);
        XYZ point = selectionHelper.SelectLineEndPoint(UIDocument);

        labelPointLocalXValue.Text = Math.Round(point.X, 3).ToString();
        labelPointLocalYValue.Text = Math.Round(point.Y, 3).ToString();
        labelPointLocalZValue.Text = Math.Round(point.Z, 3).ToString();
        Show();

        PlaceFamily(point);
    }

    private void PlaceFamily(XYZ point)
    {
        FamilySymbolHelper familySymbolHelper = new FamilySymbolHelper(Document);
        FamilyInstanceHelper familyInstanceHelper = new FamilyInstanceHelper(Document);
        FamilySymbol famSym = familySymbolHelper.FamilySymbolByName("Master-Bauteil");
        try
        {
            using (Transaction t = new Transaction(Document, "Familie platzieren"))
            {
                t.Start();
                FamilyInstance famInst = familyInstanceHelper.FamilyInstanceByPoint(famSym, point);
                t.Commit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            TaskDialog.Show("Error", e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to enter the inputs (Excelfile, Lines, Point) and then it should generate me the FamilyInstances. But i'm kinda stuck now ^^.
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You used Form.Show() method in an ExternalCommand, so it is a modeless window.
And in this window, there is a button, and the user click it and then pick an end point. 
Well, problem is: You cannot start a Transaction outside Revit API Context!
I suggest you to research Revit API samples, in which there is a directory named as "Modeless Dialog". It clearly demonstrates how to work with modeless dialog via External Event.
https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2015/12/external-event-and-10-year-forum-anniversary.html

Comment: I'm not quite sure if you did read my question but i know that i'm doing a Transaction outside of the Revit API. I also tried to understand the ModelessForm_ExternalEvent Sample from the SDK. I just wanted to know if this is the only way to solve this? Or can it be done in another way...

Comment: As far as I know, there are only 2 ways of modifying Revit data base via a modeless dialog - External Event or Idling Event. They are both demonstrated in Revit SDK samples/ModelessDialog/.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the Revit window handle to the when calling `dataInputForm.Show();`

Here is a modified code:

```
[Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
internal class DataInput : IExternalCommand
{
    private static WindowHandle _hWndRevit = null;

    private void SetHandle()
    {
        if (null == _hWndRevit)
        {
            Process process
              = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

            IntPtr h = process.MainWindowHandle;
            _hWndRevit = new WindowHandle(h);
        }
    }

    public Result Execute(
      ExternalCommandData commandData,
      ref string message,
      ElementSet elements)
    {

        SetHandle();

        UIApplication uiapp = commandData.Application;
        UIDocument uidoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument;
        Application app = uiapp.Application;
        Document doc = uidoc.Document;

        // Form instanziieren
        var dataInputForm = new DataInputForm(uidoc);
        // Form starten
        if (_hWndRevit != null)
        {
            dataInputForm.Show(_hWndRevit);
        }
        else
        {
            return Result.Failed;
        }

        return Result.Succeeded;
    }
}
```

Here is a topic in Jeremy Tammik blog about this issue:
https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2009/02/revit-window-handle-and-modeless-dialogues.html